# Как сделать ломаные с переменным цветом в Яндекс Картах?

Tags: javascript, цвета

Как сделать на Яндекс картах на ломаных переменный цвет?

То есть, чтобы шла траектория с переменным цветом. На данный момент сделал через много других ломаных, у каждой из которых разный цвет.
Но начинает подтормаживать.

[image: Текст]

Вот как сделано:

```
for (var i = 1; i < points2.length; i++) {
                      line = [points2[i], points2[i-1]];
                       // Создаем ломаную с помощью вспомогательного класса Polyline.
                      myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline(line, {
                                // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
                                // Содержимое балуна.
```

Хотелось бы оставить только одну полилинию с разным цветом по сегментам.

Comment: Язык хоть какой? Добавьте метку. JavaScript?

Comment: Да, JavaScript.